# How to apply styles to slot element in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I'd like styles declared in one module to be applied to the slot elements of that module (which get filled in in another file).

Here's a [Svelte REPL](https://svelte.technology/repl?version=1.38.0&gist=74421905020094860bce2e90625e8ed6) of the following example:

*App.html*

```
<List>
    {{#each items as item}}
        <li><a>{{item}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</List>

<script>
    import List from './List.html'

    export default {
        components: {
            List
        }
    }
</script>
```

*List.html*:

```
<h1>A Special List</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a>Let's all be red!</a></li>
    <slot></slot>
</ul>

<style>
    ul a {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

*Data*:

```
{
    "items": ["Nope", "I'm good"]
}
```

The red coloring doesn't apply to the `a` tag elements that were added through slot.
[image]

I'm very new to Svelte, but I read through as much as I could find online, and couldn't seem to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The trick here is to opt in to the cascade, using the `:global(...)` modifier. In your List component:

```html
<style>
  ul :global(a) {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

That means 'any `a` elements that are children of this component's `ul` element, whether they belong to this component or not, should be red'.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is this documented anywhere? I couldn't seem to find anything. Edit: I see it's mentioned in svelte's README under the cascade option.

Comment: Yeah, we need to do a better job of covering this in the docs themselves. I'll raise an issue for it

Comment: How to use child selector ``>`` inside ``:global()``?

Comment: Great answer.  This functionality wasn't obvious to me (hence why I'm here), and though it's documented in svelte.dev/docs#style , I missed it because I was relying on svelte/tutorial instead.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be scoped to only `a`s of `ul`s within the slotted component? Or it targets `a`s of ALL `ul`s everywhere in the document? (Assuming it's used within a slotted component.) __P.S.: I've got my answer from another forum, I'll add it here for future readers:__ "_This targets all `a`'s underneath that `ul`, since only the `a` is globally scoped it will leak into child components but not parent because the `ul` specifier is scoped._" So yeah, it's safe to use.

Answer (score 4):

For those who need to style the slot container only if it exists

Create button component

```
<button>
  {#if $$slots['start-icon']}
    <div class="m-4">
      <slot name="start-icon" />
    </div>
  {/if}

  <slot></slot>
</button>
```

Usage

```
<button>
  <Icon slot='start-icon' />

  Button name
</button>
```

See [Component composition / Checking for slot content](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/optional-slots)